# Highlighting a row thats not selected on button click angular js

Tags: angularjs, highlighting

How do I highlight a row in a table? if the rows selectbox is not selected, it must check it when the button is clicked.

what I have tried:

```
$scope.setClickedRow = function (index) {
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
}

<tr id="TableBody" ng-repeat="code in CodeRegister.CodeDetails" ng-class="{selected:$index != selectedRow}">                 
    <td ng-form="form">
      <select id="reasons" name="reasons" ng-model="code.CategoryID" ng-options=""  >
        <option  default value="">Reasons</option></select>
```

Button click:

```
<div style="margin-left:70em;" id="Save" class="ribbon-button ribbon-button-large " ng-click="CodeRegister.InsertCodeRegisterDetailss(myForm) && setClickedRow($index)">
</div>
```

Now on load it highlights everything,i only want it to highlight the rows on button clicked event and if the select box is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`ng-class="{true:'selected',false:''}[selectedRow==$index]"`

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

First, on the `<tr>` element, you should use a class instead of an id, because you are `ng-repeat`-ing it. Also, by convention, class names are dashed-case. So consider replacing :

```
<tr id="TableBody" ng-repeat="code in CodeRegister.CodeDetails" ...>
```

with

```
<tr class="table-body" ng-repeat="code in CodeRegister.CodeDetails" ...>
```

As for *"on load it highlights everything"*, this is because `$scope.selectedRow` is undefined while you didn't trigger a click. Therefore the condition `$index != selectedRow` is true, therefore you have put the class `selected` on all rows. Consider this value for `ng-class` :

```
ng-class="{selected: selectedRow && $index !== selectedRow}">
```

Comment: how does it call it on the button click since the ng-class goes on the tr

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. Can you precise it? Please also precise where did you put the button with ng-click, relatively to your `ng-repeat`-ed element, i.e. relatively to the `tr`

Comment: the button click is there in the question.its outside the table.when i click on the save button it must see which row isnt selected and highlight those rows.

Comment: If the button is outside the `ng-repeat`, then the value of `$index` you are passing to `setClickedRow` won't be the index of the row. If you can reproduce the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it will be easier to correct it.